# jquery code with show more not working

Tags: jquery, loops

I have this code that is only supposed to show one line, however instead of only showing the first line it shows the full content. When I click the "show more" button the side only scrolls up to the top.

PHP:

```
/* Inside a loop */

<?php 
    $full_text = get_the_content();
    $period_pos = strpos($full_text, ".");
    $excerpt = substr($full_text, 0, $period_pos+1);    // Get the first line, assuming that a line ends with a period.
    $rest = substr($full_text, $period_pos+1);          // Get the rest of the text  ?>  <div class="excerpt">
    <?php echo $excerpt; ?>  </div>  <div class="rest">
    <?php echo $rest; ?>  </div>  <div class="show-more-div">
    <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more</a>  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show-more").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().prev().slideDown();     
    });
});
```

Comment: Break down you question into: 1) What I want to do 2) What I have 3) What's not working. You will get more people willing to help with a better structured question.

Comment: Do you have any CSS to include?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start with the `div.rest` elements hidden using CSS.
Then, when you click the link, the appropriate div can `slideDown()`.

```
div.rest {
    display:none;
}
```

[Here's a working sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/PxejR/)

**EDIT:**

I also recommend adding `return false;` to your `click` handler in order to prevent the default click behavior for the href:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".show-more").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().slideDown();
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PxejR/1/

Comment: thanks everybody for there patient, I am still learning and I have still problems even with basics. Okay my mistake forgot the div.rest display:none, however now only the first and the last of all container are opening...

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot without seeing your actual rendered HTML/CSS. Here's a sample with multiple content blocks: http://jsfiddle.net/PxejR/2/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".show-more").on("click",function(){

       $(this).parent().prev().slideDown();     
  });
```

Comment: Where do you see a loop that adds a div after DOM loads? The loop appears to be written in PHP and is executed server-side before the page is served.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback.But using `on` is best option rather than`click`.